# CSS iPod : Capture click wheel movement

Tags: jquery, html, css, ipod

I'm making a CSS iPod (first generation). I have managed to get the layout right, including the click wheel and the 4 buttons (menu, play/pause, prev, next).
But these buttons are not rectangular. However HTML elements are rectangular. So if the user clicks the 'menu' button, the click wheel will ge the one which receives the click.
How can I accurately get the user's intended click?

Also how can I detect the scrolling of the click wheel?

Here is my iPod.
http://inventikasolutions.com/demo/iPod

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create polygonal hotspot using the  tag ( see http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_area.asp ) to know when specific areas are clicked. Other solutions involve using a color-map in a canvas and sampling the color at the same location to decide what action to take.

For the scrolling, you'll want to calculate the angle at which the pointer is at relative to the centre of the wheel when the mousedown is first fired, and keep calculating the change in angle as mousemove is repeatedly fired as the pointer is dragged. Then you can evaluate the difference in angles to know a scroll has happened and how fast.

Comment: thanks, I have found this nifty jQuery plugin for the Click Wheel scrolling. http://tutorialzine.com/2011/11/pretty-switches-css3-jquery/

For the clicking issue, i would prefer not to use SVGs or Canvas. I'm using a gradient for the wheel, so trying to find the color value won't be useful.

Comment: You wouldn't use the color value of the wheel - you'd have a hidden image with just simple solid colors on it that isn't shown to the user with a different color for each function. When a user clicks on a part of the wheel, you find what color is at that same position in your hidden image and perform a different function depending on the color picked.